# $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$-estimate for solution of heat equation with Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, semigroup-of-operators

$\Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$, consider the heat equation on $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary condition
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u -\Delta u=0 & (t,x)\in (0,\infty)\times \Omega\\
u(0,x)=u_0(x) & (t,x)\in \{0\}\times \Omega \\
u(t,x)=0 & (t,x)\in (0,\infty)\times \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
By semigroup theory, Laplacian operator $\Delta:H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$, generates a bounded analytic semigroup $E(t)=e^{t\Delta}$ on $L^2(\Omega)$. Thus for $u_0\in L^2(\Omega)$, there is solution $u(t,\cdot)=E(t)u_0\in H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega), \forall t>0$ satisfying the equation and $\|u(t,\cdot)-u_0\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to 0$ when $t\to 0$, with $\|u(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C\|u_0\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$.

My question is, if we moreover assume that $u_0\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$, is there exists following gradient estimation:

$$
\|u(t,\cdot)\|_{W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)}\leq C\|u_0\|_{W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)} \quad \forall t>0,
$$
where $C$ is a constant independent of $u_0$ and $t$.

Comment: You are asking two different questions in the title and the body of the post.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I edited the title.

Comment: First note that $e^{t\Delta}$ is contractive on $L^\infty$. I described here how one can prove this using quadratic form methods: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245707/short-time-l1-bounds-for-semigroups-obtained-from-elliptic-operators/246869#246869. Alternatively, this also follows from heat kernel comparison. As for the $L^\infty$ norm of the gradients, this is true if $\Omega$ is a closed Riemannian manifold by Bakry-Émery theory. For domains I don't know the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!